# how to get all possible solutions to delete duplicate items from a list (python)

Tags: python, list

If I have a list like this [C, B, A, B]
and I want to get all possible solutions to remove duplicates: [C, B, A], [C, A, B]
How can I get this result in pure python?

Comment: `list(set([C, B, A, B]))`, hope this gives you the desired result?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel did you run it? (it doesn't give the result OP lists in the question)

Comment: According to the question, the order does matter, so that isn’t a duplicate.

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt to solve this into your question (StackOverflow isn’t a coding service)

Comment: Is this what you expect `[('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B')]`?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel no, they expect `["C", "B", "A"], ["C", "A", "B"]`

Answer (score 3):

Here, I believe, is an approach that works. First, create a mapping from all the items in the list to their indices:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = ['C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G','H','D', 'J']
>>> grouped = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, e in enumerate(data):
...     grouped[e].append(i)
...
>>> grouped
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': [0], 'B': [1, 4], 'D': [2, 6, 9], 'A': [3], 'E': [5], 'G': [7], 'H': [8], 'J': [10]})
```

Then, you can simply find the product of all these indices, and reconstitute a list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for idx in itertools.product(*grouped.values()):
...     idx = sorted(idx)
...     print([data[i] for i in idx])
...
['C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'D', 'J']
['C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['C', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['C', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'D', 'J']
```

Not sure if it is the most elegant. And think there is an edge-case where you will end up with the same result multiple times, e.g. `['C', 'A','A','B']` would give `['C','A','B'], ['C','A','B']`, but it isn't clear if that is undesirable, if it is, you could just filter out *those* duplicates, maybe using a set. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :)